# The number of coprime integer solutions of: $ N=p x^2+q y^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p,q$ be a pair of coprime positive integers. Let $S(N,p,q)$ be the number of integer solutions $(x,y)$ of $N=p x^2+q y^2$ such that $x$ and $y$ are coprime.  If $(p,q)=(1,1)$, it follows from Fermat's two square theorem that $S(N,1,1)$ has no upper bound as $N\to\infty$. What will happens if $(p,q)\neq(1,1)$, i.e. is the sequence $\{S(N,p,q)\}_{N\geq1}$ still unbounded? Does there exist $(p,q)$ such that $\{S(N,p,q)\}_{N\geq1}$ is a bounded sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be a positive definite binary quadratic form. For a positive number $Z$ put $N_F(Z)$ for the number of pairs of integers $(x,y)$ such that $F(x,y) \leq Z$, and let $R_F(Z)$ denote the number of integers $n \leq Z$ such that the equation $F(x,y) = n$ has solutions in integers $x$ and $y$. It is easy to see from a geometry of numbers argument that

$$\displaystyle N_F(Z) \sim A_F Z$$

for a positive number $A_F$, and it is known (first by Landau in the case $F(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and in general by the thesis of one of his students) that there exists a positive number $C_F$ such that

$$\displaystyle R_F(Z) \sim C_F Z (\log Z)^{-1/2}.$$

From these asymptotic formulas one can conclude, in your notation, that $S(n,p,q)$ behaves like $\sqrt{\log n}$ on average; in particular, it is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any reference for the results of Landau and his student?